# Signed inno exe extremely slow on windows 7+

Tags: windows, inno-setup

I find that under certain conditions my signed, inno created installer.exe takes about 10 minutes to open or view properties.  When I run as administrator it is immediate, so it seems obvious that the UAC is somehow related.  The size of the exe is around 13 MB.

If I copy the file via thumb drive to the target machine, there is no wait.  If the same file is downloaded through a browser, there is the 10 minute wait, with explorer going into la la land doing who knows what.  After the 10 minute or so wait, the file opens normally with no wait on all subsequent openings.

I am using ksign + commodo to sign the inno exe, and an internal dotnet exe within the inno setup, although I don't think that is a factor.

Windows 10 has the 10 minute wait even running as administrator.

This action is happening for most versions from win 7 on up.  There seems to be some change in the exe contents that triggered it, but I haven't found the reason.

Edit 1:  I previously contacted ksign, they don't seem to have any issues with my exe, it opens without lag in their environment.  This isn't typical however, as many installations face this lag issue.  I also tried making some sense out of process monitor monitoring explorer, but there is too much information going on with explorer to pick out the hanging process, unless I a looking in the wrong place.

Edit 2: MsMpEng.exe, which is microsoft security essentials, seems to running amok. This goes on almost endlessly.[image: sysinternals]

Comment: I've noticed a longer delay since Windows 8.1 (in seconds though). Have you tried to sign a non-installer executable to eliminate the issue with installers (or Inno Setup explicitly) ?

Comment: Further testing would almost indicate Microsoft Security Essentials as playing some part in this.

Comment: But 10 minutes is insanely long time. Does it happen with any signed application (not only installer) ?

Comment: No.  Most signed stuff works as expected.

Comment: My next (but probably last) guess is missing supported OS flag for Windows 10 in Inno Setup (as long as you are not using your own build of not yet released v5.5.6, or your own clone). But that would not explain why do you observe this lag on systems other than Windows 10.

Comment: I would suggest to trace the installer with ProcMon. https://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessMonitor.zip You will see what's going on and where the time is spend.

Comment: Any suggestions which filters?

Comment: Yes, filter the installer executable itself. Its `"Process Name" "is" "your-app-setup.exe" "include"`. Or start exe and include it via the right-click context menu in procmon.

Comment: First, make sure that your executable is countersigned by a timestamp server.  Second, some delay seems to be inevitable for signed files when Windows *thinks* that it has an Internet connection but it is being blocked by something (eg. firewall).  The delay is also longer if the file is larger because part of the UAC validation is calculating a checksum of the entire file.  10 minutes seems excessive for such a small file however.

Answer (score 2):

Try steps described here: [Offline Environment and Authenticode](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw#offline-environment-and-authenticode):

> To work with UAC-enabled Windows, winsw ships with a digital
>   signature. This causes Windows to automatically verify this digital
>   signature when the application is launched (see [more
>   discussions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb629393.aspx)).
>   This adds some delay to the launch of the service, and more
>   importantly, it prevents winsw from running in a server that has no
>   internet connection. This is because a part of the signature
>   verification involves checking certificate revocation list.
>
> To prevent this problem, create `myapp.exe.config` in the same
>   directory as `myapp.exe` (renamed `winsw.exe`) and put the following
>   in it:
>
> ```
> <configuration>
>   <runtime>
>     <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/> 
>   </runtime>
> </configuration>
> ```
>
> See [KB 936707](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/936707) for more
>   details.

Note, this may not work, if your installer already has embedded manifest ([more details](http://csi-windows.com/blog/all/27-csi-news-general/245-find-out-why-your-external-manifest-is-being-ignored)). In this case you should try to modify your embedded manifest instead.