# Inno Setup slow startup

Tags: inno-setup

Found my answer here: [Signed inno exe extremely slow on windows 7+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30957160/signed-inno-exe-extremely-slow-on-windows-7)
I created an installer using inno setup that weights 6.5m 
When I finish downloading this installer I try to open it.
Sometimes it opens in a matter of seconds and sometimes it takes it more the ONE MINUTE to open.
How can I minimize the time it takes to open the installer.
The delay happens before the UAC prompt.
The Installer is signed.

Comment: Is the delay before or after a UAC prompt?

Comment: before the UAC prompt

Comment: Is your installer signed?

Comment: Yes the installer is signed

Comment: Did you try to turn off SmartScreen?

Comment: Turning off SmartScreen is not an option for me.

Comment: Of course not. But you want to know if it is the SmartScreen that is causing the delay.

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/30957160/960757